# Query works in Query Designer but not in MS SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, query-designer, ora-01843

While using the Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder, I am able to execute a query in the Query Designer and retreive the result. The query has a where clause on dates.

```
select * from table where DB_timestamp > to_date(:StartDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy') and DB_timestamp <  to_date(:EndDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

On execution, I get a pop up where I enter the two variables (StartDate & EndDate) in the given formats. Now when I try to run the same for generating a report, I have to select the two variables using a calender picker. Altough the dates show up in the desired format, I always get the below error:

```
An error occured during local report processing.
 Query execution failed for dataset 'XYZ'.
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

What can cause the query to run successfully in one place but throw an error when the variables are selected by the calender picker?

Comment: what if you date and month are below 12? same error? is it possible to submit parameter as date rather than string?

Comment: Perhaps culture settings are messing things up? (i.e. SSRS sending dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: @Jeroen Thank you for the comment ... it helped me go in the right direction. If you post that as an answer, i'll gladly accept it :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If there were more relevant details be sure to edit my answer and add them; maybe it'll help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There mught be some kind of culture clash going on. If SSRS is sending dd/mm/yyyy and your db is expecting mm/dd/yyyy things will not work as expected or even crash on certain dates.

Comment: Thanks Joren. The issue was the date format. My database was expecting 'DD-MON-RR'!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the to_date function from the where clause, e.g.

`where DB_timestamp > :StartDate and ...`